# DBeaver Database Navigator settings - Why is "Show all tables in a single list" disabled?

Tags: dbeaver, windows-11

I have a database with many separate logical schemas and would like to be able to view all tables in a single list prefixed with the schema name (similar to SSMS). DBeaver seems to support this with a "Show all tables in a single list" option, but the option is disabled for me. How can it be enabled?

To get to this setting, in the DBeaver Database Navigator, right-click the connection and go to "Connection view... Custom".
[image: Navigate to custom connection view]

For me, the "Show all tables in a single list" is always disabled. I've checked connecdtions to both MySQL and MS SQL Server.

[image: Custom connection view options]

I've also looked through "Window... Preferences" but have not found a way to enable the "single list" option.

I'm running DBeaver v.23.2.5 on Windows 11.

Comment: Seems a bug... https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/13565

Comment: Thanks, yes, that issue seems to be related, although it's not precisely what I'm seeing. I don't get an error. It's just that the option is unavailable -- as the https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/13565#issuecomment-1117605908 comment indicates.